# Why "RangeError: Invalid status code: 0", firebase functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

With the following functions called as http request:

```
exports.newID = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let citiesRef = fireStore.collection('system').doc('uid_counter');
  let snapshot = await citiesRef.get();
  let counter = snapshot.get('counter');
  console.log('current counter = ', counter);
  res.status(200).send(counter);
```

The firebase functions console.log indicate that counter can be gotten well, but response gets an error:

[image]

I have no idea why I've gotten "RangeError: Invalid status code: 0" despite I've specified **status(200)**. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Express [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) for `res.send([body])` states that

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an
>   Array.

So sending a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is most probably the cause of your problem.

You could send the `counter` value as an object, as follows:

```
res.status(200).send({ counter: counter});
```

Comment: thank you so mush, was stuck on this for like days