# How to get data returned from a Firebase Function using fetch?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, fetch, httprequest

Currently I have the following function:

```
exports.loginDriver = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
    const motorista = await admin
      .database()
      .ref(`motoristas/${body.cpf}`)
      .once("value");
    
    // Se não existe o token, motorista não cadastrado
    if (motorista.val().token === null || motorista.val().token === undefined) {
      response.status(400).send({ error, message: "Motorista não encontrado" });
    } else {
      const bytes = AES.decrypt(motorista.val().token, motorista.val().cpf);
      const senha = bytes.toString(enc);
      if (senha === body.senha) {
        response.status(200).send(motorista.val());
      } else {
        response.send(400).send({ message: "CPF ou senha inválidos" });
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send({ error, message: "Erro ao realizar o login" });
  }
});
```

And I call it from my frontend like this:

```
async doLogin() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({backdropDismiss: false, message: 'Aguarde...'});
    await loading.present();
    try {
      if (this.loginForm.valid) {
        this.formInvalid = false;
        const user: Response = await this._auth.login(this.loginForm.value);
        console.log('response', await user.json());
        await this._storage.set('user', user);
        await loading.dismiss();
        await this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/home');
      } else {
        this.formInvalid = true;
        await loading.dismiss();
        alert('Preencha os dados corretamente');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      await loading.dismiss();
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

/* My _auth service which has the login method */
async login(data) {
    try {
      return await fetch('https://myCloudFunctionsUrl/loginDriver', {
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
```

But I receive the following return which is from Response type:

```
body: (...) // it's null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {} // empty
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response
```

I tried using .blob() and .json(), but I wasn't able to get the data I'm sending to my frontend. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`const body = JSON.parse(request.body)` doesn't do what you think in Cloud Functions.  For a POST with JSON content type, `request.body` comes pre-populated with deserialized JSON.  See the documentation on [handling content types](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_content_types).  Instead of parsing `request.body`, just use it as a normal JS object.

If you absolutely must handle parsing of the request on your own, you can use `request.rawBody` instead, but I don't think that will buy you anything.

Comment: Okay, thanks, will do that. But sadly this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ensure that the sent type of `motoristas.val()` is compatible with the `send` API.

See [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60337624/3088045).